# Writing a grouping query in sql ( MS-Access )

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I have two tables Projects and Invoices. The database is MS Access ( mdb )

Project table has fields

1. ProjectID
2. ProjectName
3. ProjectStatus

Invoices table has the fields

1. InvoiceID
2. ProjectID ( foreign key )
3. InvoiceType ( Paid and Recieved )
4. InvoiceChannel ( Coding, Designing and Consulting )
5. InvoiceAmount

The Projects table is in a one-to-many relation with Invoices table with Project ID as foreign key.

I want a table created from querying the Invoices table like this

[image: Grouping problem in MS Access]

How can I achieve this using an SQL query?
Or do I have to do it using server side coding ( I use C#  with ASP.NET )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted table schema doesn't have a field that contains the amount to sum. I will refer to it as `Amount`.

First, create a crosstab query, and save it in the database (I've called it `ct`):

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Amount) AS SumOfAmount
SELECT ProjectID, InvoiceType
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY ProjectID, InvoiceType
PIVOT InvoiceChannel In ("Coding","Designing","Consulting");
```

This will give you the `ProjectID` and the `InvoiceType` as the first two columns, with one additional column each for "Coding","Designing" and "Consulting".

To get the total, you need another query:

```
SELECT ct.*, Coding + Designing + Consulting AS Total
FROM ct;
```

Bear in mind that if there are no records for a particular `ProjectID`/`InvoiceType`/`InvoiceChannel`, the query will return `NULL` for that combination, which will result in the `Total` being `NULL`. If this query will be running under Access (say via `Access.Application`) you can use the `Nz` function, which works like the `??` operator in C#:

```
SELECT ct.*, Nz(Coding,0) + Nz(Designing,0) + Nz(Consulting,0) AS Total
FROM ct;
```

If you are accessing data from an `.mdb` or `.accdb` via ADO.NET using the OleDbProvider, you probably won't be able to use `Nz`, and you'll have to use something more complex:

```
SELECT ct.*, 
    Iif(IsNull(Coding), 0, Coding) +
    Iif(IsNull(Designing), 0, Designing) + 
    Iif(IsNull(Consulting), 0, Consulting) AS Total
FROM ct;
```

Comment: sorry. i have updated question. plus i dont need cross tab query. i am just concerned about querying the single table `Invoices`. I will try your method and let you know. thanks...

Comment: How will you get the data from your `Invoices` table in the form you want without a crosstab query?

Comment: lets just say i have all the project ids from which i want the invoices count. both tables are in different mdbs

Comment: Hi ZevSpitz. Nice answer, but you do not need another query to get a total in a crosstab, you can additionally sum the value field as a row heading. For example: `TRANSFORM Sum(Table1.ANumber) AS SumOfANumber
SELECT Table1.AText2, Sum(Table1.ANumber) AS Total
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.AText2
PIVOT Table1.AText;`